# Terminal not opening on Ubuntu 22.04 on Virtual box 7.0.0

Tags: command-line, 22.04, virtualbox

I'm using windows 10 and I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on Virtual box 7.0.0.

When I click the terminal icon, the upper left side of the screen(where is the executing application name view), there is the title 'Terminal' and a turning arrow that indicates it's launching.

[image]

But somehow it blows away and the terminal is not opening and really executing.

I'm not sure it's about Ubuntu or Virtual machine too. How can I fix this?

Comment: From your question "But somehow it blows away and the terminal is not opening and really executing." can you explain what this means?

Comment: David, sorry for the confusing writing. I meant the 'terminal' letter and arrow disappear while the terminal is not opening and not executing.

Comment: ChanganAuto, I tried CTRL+ALT+T but it didn't work. My Ubuntu and Virtualbox are up to date. The extension pack and guest additions are also installed.

Comment: So, what exactly you've done since installing Ubuntu? Did you perhaps tried to change the phyton version?

Comment: ChanganAuto, I did change nothing after installing Ubuntu. After installing it, I started the terminal right away, but the situation above happened. So I updated the Ubuntu through GUI and installed the lastest extention package of Virtual box that is for my version, but nothing changed.

Comment: Simplest solution: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NvTMQBxGqDw

Comment: Creating another administrator account solved my problem.

Comment: I just changed the Settings/Language and Region/Language from english to english(Canada), and then I restarted the VM and I could open the terminal without any issue.

Comment: Bizar..........

Answer (score 53):

Same on vbox 7.0, I had fixed it adding `en_US.UTF-8` instead of `en_US` to the `/etc/default/locale` then `sudo locale-gen --purge` and reboot.

As pointed out in the comments, one can also do this via: `Settings>Region & Language>` and setting all settings to `United States`.

**Note:** Both solutions are applied **inside** the Virtualbox Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Method of Mike Lugin works. I changed the language (just to another one, I chose UK) in the UI Settings -> Language and Region, the VM restarted and Terminal works.

Comment: @MargaretM Thanks, this worked!

Comment: I can not open a terminal -> Go open a terminal and do the following XD

Comment: Did not work for me

Comment: How to edit /etc/default/locale when I don't have Terminal to run, e.g., `sudo gedit /etc/default/locale` ? I can launch gedit from the menu, but then seem to lack the 'sudo' rights required to save the changes to /etc/default/locale

Comment: Hi @FlorianH, try to switch session using (CTRL+ALT+F3), it will promt you to a cli where you can use sudo, then you can edit locale using nano and switch back to GUI using (CTRL+ALT+F1).

Comment: Thanks @Mike Lugin, sounds like it might have worked. In the meantime instead I simply evaded the issue by re-installing my Virtualbox@Win10 installation of Ubuntu16.04 first _without Guest Additions_, before adding them post-hoc.

Comment: I could do the change using GUI by going to Settings > Region & Language, then setting all to US.

Comment: This worked. I just can't believe that Ubuntu would ship out a build with such obviously wrong configurations.

Comment: How do you do this without terminal?

Comment: As suggested, changing the language from Settings menu fixed the problem. The default was en-US, I have changed to Türkçe.

Comment: Not able to save the changes in locale file since it is read only.

Comment: @SanushiSalgado Try `sudo nano /etc/default/locale`

Answer (score 25):

I got this issue with VB 7.2 on Windows 11, My findings:

1. If you use unattended, created user will not even has sudo rights so that you can not update/edit "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal" with python version or purge gnome-terminal.
   Even updates doe not work with the created user.
2. As suggested above,  skip the unattended [As shown in snip below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcroR.png)

After installation all worked.
[Terminal worked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDcTE.png)

Comment: Did the bidirectional copy and paste function works with `Skip Unattended Installation` checked?

Answer (score 18):

I've spent 3h to fix this problem (Win 10 Pro, Vbox 7.0) and finally, I've decided to re-install a new guest OS with `Skip Unattended Installation` **checked**

Comment: Did the bidirectional copy and paste function works with `Skip Unattended Installation` checked?

Comment: bidirectional copy and paste function works well as usual

Comment: by reinstalling Ubuntu on VB as suggested, I get the terminal running, the keyboard recognized correctly and VM User Interface showed.   Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem. The first thing I tried after installing Ubuntu 22.04 in VirtualBox 7.0 was to start the terminal. But it didn't work.

My solution was to create a new VM with a new installation. This time I selected "Skip unattended installation" when I created the VM, so that the Guest Additions was not automatically installed. Now I could start the terminal! After this I installed the Guest Additions using `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso`. In this way I got an old version of the Guest Additions, but that version seems to work fine.

So obviously the problem is related to the Guest Additions.

Comment: Did the bidirectional copy and paste function works with `Skip Unattended Installation` checked?

Comment: Yes, it works now after one and a half months but I could not figure out the reason.

Answer (score 5):

I've been cracking my brain all day with the same problem. The only solution was to install a version of VB lower than 7.0

Answer (score 1):

Switch Ubuntu to X11 instead of Wayland.

Also you can try to switch off 3d acceleration in the machine settings.

I just installed VB 7.0.2 and also had some trouble with graphics.

Finally all works with X11 and 3D enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for my Virtualbox 7.0 with host Windows 10 and guest Ubuntu 22.04.

1. Start Virtualbox machine and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> quickly until the grub boot menu is shown.
2. Go to Advanced options for Ubuntu and boot in recovery mode.
3. Drop to root shell prompt (will ask for root password)
4. sudo adduser username sudo (change username with your username)
5. Change everything in /etc/default/locale to be 'en_US.UTF-8', I used nano.
6. reboot